# RVM throws gems directory permission error during bundle install / rake assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

On an EC2 ubuntu t1.micro instance, using RVM to manage ruby. When cucumber was added to the Gemfile and bundler was ran to install , it installs some dependent gems like gherkin.

Subsequently, when rails assets:precompile is ran , rvm throws the following permissions error. Any directions from here would be helpful

```
 $ rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production --trace
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `mkdir': Permission denied - /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.0.0/gherkin-2.12.2 (Errno::EACCES)
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `fu_mkdir'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:219:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `reverse_each'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `block in mkdir_p'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `each'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `mkdir_p'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:210:in `write_gem_make_out'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:132:in `build_error'
```

ON subsequent trouble shooting by removing the gem and installing it natively also throws permission error.

```
$ gem install gherkin
Fetching: gherkin-2.12.2.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied - /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/gherkin-2.12.2/.gitattributes
```

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by running blunder as sudo user

```
$rvmsudo bundle install
```

Still not sure why the permission issue was coming for non super user.

Comment: Did you originally install rvm as root (or using sudo)? Check the permissions on `/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353`. I suspect it's owned by root and not writable by the `ubuntu` user.

Comment: RVM was installed as ubuntu user.I checked the permissions and they seem to be okay ??         `drwxrwxr-x 10 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K Mar 13  2014 ruby-2.0.0-p353@global
drwxrwxr-x 11 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K Mar 13  2014 ruby-2.0.0-p353`

Comment: You're also running rake as `ubuntu`? Are the permissions the same on subdirectories?

Comment: Yes rake is run as ubuntu user. I see an issue with the sub directories. Some of them are owned by root - why would this happen ? `ubuntu@ip-172-31-17-23:~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353$ ls -althr
-rw-rw-r--   1 ubuntu ubuntu environment
drwxr-xr-x   3 root   root   extensions
drwxr-xr-x   3 root   root   bundler
drwxrwxr-x  11 ubuntu ubuntu .
drwxr-xr-x   5 root   root   doc
drwxrwxr-x   2 ubuntu ubuntu wrappers
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root   build_info
drwxrwxr-x   2 ubuntu ubuntu bin
drwxrwxr-x   3 ubuntu ubuntu cache
drwxr-xr-x 191 root   root   gems
drwxrwxr-x   2 ubuntu ubuntu specifications`

Comment: Maybe you used sudo or otherwise ran as root the first time you ran Bundler. It would have created those directories for the first time owned by root, which would then prevent a non-root user from installing into them subsequently.

Comment: I remember installing it the first time as non-root user (ubuntu) and things were working fine with multiple deployments. Recently the permission issues started showing up for the first time and had to use `rvmsudo` while running bundler , do you think that would have changed it ? Any thoughts on the best practices for getting back to normal from here ?

Comment: Well, the nuclear option is to `rvm implode` and reinstall everything, but you could probably get away with a `sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu/.rvm`.